# Python - time data does not match format

Tags: python

I have a date format that looks like this `Apr 9 2018` and would like to convert it to something like `2018-04-19`

My sample code looks like this:

`datetime.strptime(unformated_date, '%m %d %y').strftime('%y-%m-%d')` where `unformated_date="Apr 9 2018"`

But I am getting the error `time data ' Apr 9 2018' does not match format '%m %d %y'`

How could I achieve this in python? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use datetime or dateutils library. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date string is `"%b %d %Y"`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
unformated_date = "Apr 9 2018"    
print( datetime.datetime.strptime(unformated_date, "%b %d %Y").strftime('%y-%m-%d') )
print( datetime.datetime.strptime(unformated_date, "%b %d %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d') )
```

**Output:**

```
18-04-09
2018-04-09
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)**

Comment: Thanks!  what does the 'b' mean?

Comment: `%b` == Month as locale’s abbreviated name.

Comment: Is there a way for the year to show up as '2018' instead of just '18' ?

Comment: Sure use `%Y` capital Y